# Optical data discs recognized writeable/empty all the time

Tags: windows-8, dvd, compact-disc

strange problem:

Putting a CDROM into my DVD burner only shows (Windows explorer shows) an empty/burnable media. Both for home made CD, but also orignal (software) data CD. Video DVDs show their content. Original (software) also show content, but offer to burn additional data to it. Self made data DVD dont show their content.

Drive is a PX880 attached internally via SATA. I also attached an external (USB) DVD burner from Samsung -> exactly the same. Therefore I can safely assume, that neither the tested media (several) nor the drive itself is the problem and more likely its a software/driver problem.

System is Win 8.1/64. Last time I tested (maybe several weeks or months , bc I dont use CD/DVD not very often anymore) everything worked. Of course I have installed software etc since then - but I have done that since years ;)

any ideas?

UPDATE: Nailed it down a bit. cdfs.sys was not started (so Win doesn't recognize the file system and therfore thinks its an empty CD/DVD) and were set to "do not start". I tried to start cdfs.sys manually (sc start cdfs.sys), but failed bc:

> "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source."

Same happens if I let it start during system startup (start type: automatic).

I compared cdfs.sys with a working version from another PC -> ok
I ran "sfc /SCANNOW" but it did not show any problems for cdfs.sys .

So the question is: Why doesn't Windows want to start cdfs.sys?

Comment: Shows like user error and/or selecting the wrong options when using the built-in capability to burn a disk in Windows.  What options are you selecting exactly?  The files are there more then likely its just that the "session" was never closed so its only visible on the machine that wrote the disk.

Comment: I've never used windows burning (CDBurnerXP is always one of the first programs I install. And "mastered" CDs usually don't contain sessions. Even the self made discs HAVE worked before of course (because I even finalize if the disc only contains 4MB)

Comment: You should update your question to reflect all that information.  because honestly..It sounds like the problem in my office, people don't know how to use the built-in tool, and were burning disks wrong and not actually closing the session.

Comment: Do all drives have their latest firmware? Not sure about situation in 2010+, but I remember that firmware updates in the 2000th were almost a must-have if you wanted your drives to fully function all the time. The drive manufacturers added a lot of supported media types, read and write options, region-(un)locking and OS support just by firmware updates (which sometimes were released on a monthly basis).

Comment: External USB-Drive tested too. Works fine and reads all discs on two PC and shows the same problem as the built-in drive on the third.

Comment: @igrimpe Did you try on the non-working PC to use a third party tool to view the contents of the disk? To check if it really is a Windows problem. I remember ISO Buster (http://www.isobuster.com/) being pretty good (it uses it's own logic to acces the drive and not the Windows API).

Comment: updated question

Comment: Which Windows version and which PX880 model? In case of driver error, try the old remedy of deleting the device in Device Manager and rebooting. If the driver is not Microsoft-generic, try to reinstall it. See also if in Windows Update there is an optional driver update. Look also for a firmware update.

Comment: Windows version: see question. Firmware: nothing new. External (USB) Sasmung DVD Writer (SE-208) has the exact same problem on this machine anyway, but works ok on two others.

Comment: Looks more like a driver problem, where same driver is used for both. What happens when you do the driver operations as in my comment above?

Comment: Driver is from MS for both. Version 6.3.9600.16384 from 2006. Latest available. Driver uninstall already tried. Doesnt help. All Windows updates until NOW are installed. Even all optional (and 3rd Party drivers) except for "Bing Desktop".

Comment: (1) Is [this](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/cd_dvd_drive_problems/en-us) the fixit you tried? (2) Is the drive shared? (3) Did you do the [UpperFilters/LowerFilters trick](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/driverssupport/ss/upperfilters-lowerfilters-sbs.htm)? (4) Do you have the same problems on DVD and CD?

Comment: (5) Did you find your cdfs.sys in C:\Windows\System32\drivers ?

Comment: 1-yes, 2-no, 3-yes, 4-yes, 5-If not, it would probably difficult to use "sc" to start it ;) cdfs.sys is in the write place (also in the "backup" place WinSxs) is according to sfc not corrupted and binary is identical to the version that works on another machine.

Comment: In Windows 7 the cdfs service doesn't exist and yet my drive works very well. Microsoft in Windows 8 has given up on CDs, so some Windows Update might explain this problem. Try this [HP Troubleshooter](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c03370738) or as much as applies to your drive and report on results. Try also to install some well-known third-party CD product that is advertised for Windows 8. (I myself will avoid Windows 8 for as long as possible.)

Comment: If it would be an update problem, it should happen on any Win 8.1 PC, shouldn't it? CD burning (with CDBurnerXP) WORKS! It's reading which doesn't work.

Comment: I had a problem recently on an old Windows 2000 machine where I could write to optical discs, but then Windows wasn't able to read them.  I fixed the problem by using Nero BurnRights (available at the bottom of this page: http://www.nero.com/enu/downloads/) to reset the CD/DVD drive-related permissions.  But I don't know if Nero BurnRights is compatible with Windows 8.

Comment: Also I assume Windows 8 still has the ability to go back to a previous restore point.  That is something you might want to consider.

Comment: It could be a MS problem specific to your PX880 (which sub-model is it?).

Comment: Problem can not be related to a single drive, because I also tested an external USB Samsung Writer.

Comment: To resume: Something happened on your computer that caused a problem with all CD/DVD drives. The most potentially destructive program I know is Windows Update, so I assume that this is what has changed. As I see it, your only option in this case is to reinstall Windows 8.1 from scratch, and without guarantee of success. Before going this way, try running in a Virtual Machine another Windows version, or even a vanilla version of Windows 8.1 _without_ the latest updates.

Comment: According to the manual (http://ftp6.nero.com/user_guides/nero12/burnrights/NeroBurnRights_en-US.pdf), Nero BurnRights runs on Windows 8.  Definitely give it a try before re-installing Windows 8.

Comment: Since you are using a Microsoft-generic driver, you could try to see if the problem persists when booting in Safe mode. If it doesn't, then some installed product is causing the problem. If it does happen, then the problem is with Windows itself.

Answer (score 0):

## Preliminary Answers

> Nailed it down a bit. cdfs.sys was not started (so Win doesn't recognize the file system and therfore thinks its an empty CD/DVD) and were set to "do not start".

That was probably done by some third-party software you have installed.

> I tried to start cdfs.sys manually (sc start cdfs.sys), but failed bc:
>
> > "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file. A recent hardware or software change might have installed a file that is signed incorrectly or damaged, or that might be malicious software from an unknown source."

That certainly doesn’t sound good, but unfortunately, the message may be misleading and not actually pointing to the real cause.

> I compared cdfs.sys with a working version from another PC -> ok I ran "sfc /SCANNOW" but it did not show any problems for cdfs.sys.

If the file is not different, then like I said, the problem is not actually with `cdfs.sys`, but with something else.

> So the question is: Why doesn't Windows want to start cdfs.sys?

## Dependencies and Service Groups

It is likely a problem with one of its dependencies. The `CDFS` service depends on the `SCSI CDROM Class` group which means that the drivers and services in that group must be loaded before the *CDFS* service can be run. Therefore, you should be checking which driver or service in that group is failing.

## CDROM Driver

Generally, the only service or drive in the aforementioned group will be the `CDROM` driver, so make sure that is started (and set to automatic-startup) before checking if *CDFS* will run.

First, you can verify that Windows (or more to the point, the *CDROM* driver) is aware of your drive by using the registry-editor to check if it is listed at this key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Cdrom\Enum
```

There should be a value with a numeric name (e.g., `0`) which contains something starting with `IDE\CdRom` (yes, even with a SATA drive), followed by your drive name, firmware revision, and other data. For your drive it would be something similar to these (guessing at the sub-model and installed firmware of your drive):

```
CdRomPLEXTOR_DVDR_PX-880U_______________1.12____\…
CdRomPLEXTOR_DVDR_PX-880SA______________1.13____\…
```

If you have set the CDROM driver to autostart and verified that it is running, yet the *CDFS* driver still won’t run, it may be a third-party program that has installed something that is interfering. The next step is to check the upper and lower driver filters for your optical drive.

## Driver Filters

The easiest and safest way to check and remove problematic filters for optical drives is to use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/)’s built-in function at *Tools→Filter Driver Load Order* (figure 1). Check for any third-party filters (figure 2), and use the `[Remove Selected Filters]` button to delete them. The default list of a clean Windows installation is shown in figure 3.

## ATAPI Driver

If that *still* doesn’t work (make sure to reboot between modifications to ensure that they take effect since we are messing with drivers which are not easily changed without a reboot), then you can move to the next level and check if the *CDROM* driver itself is having trouble starting up. It depends on the `SCSI miniport` group. By default, there are only two items in the that group: `ATAPI` and `DISK`. Presumably the *DISK* driver is working, otherwise Windows wouldn’t be able to boot since it is stored on the hard-drive which uses the *DISK* driver.

Therefore, you should make sure that the *ATAPI* driver is running. Usually, that shouldn’t have any problems, but it is possible that Nero installed its own version (replacing the *ATAPI* driver was a common practice in the old days for various reasons). Check that `ATAPI.SYS` is the original version that comes with Windows and that the driver is running and set to automatic.

## RAID Drivers and Third-Party (e.g., Drive Emulation) Software

Finally, the last (common) cause of your issue is a third-party miniport driver. If your system has RAID, then Windows should have an appropriate driver installed for it, and it will likely be a *SCSI miniport* driver (which remember, the *CDROM* driver depends on). Check that you have the right drivers installed for your motherboard/RAID-controller and that they are correctly running (you can see them in the *Device Manager* by selecting *View → Show hidden devices*; they will usually be listed under the *Non-Plug and Play Drivers* branch).

Another common driver that can cause problems is that of Daemon Tools. It too uses a miniport driver in the *SCSI miniport* group, so if you have that installed, try uninstalling it to see if your drive’s functionality is restored.

---

## Diagrams

**Figure 1**: Screenshot of ImgBurn’s Filter Driver Load Order command

[image: Screenshot of ImgBurn’s Filter Driver Load Order command]

**Figure 2**: Screenshot of ImgBurn’s filter list with third-party drivers

[image: Screenshot of ImgBurn’s filter list with third-party drivers]

**Figure 3**: Screenshot of ImgBurn with a clean filter driver list

[image: Screenshot of ImgBurn with a clean filter driver list]

Comment: Done all (and more). Still my drive (resp. Windows Explorer) fails miserably when I ask it to show the contents of (for example) a stupid f*** driver disc :(
Yes, I could try a system restore point. But: the second oldest is about 2-3 days before i NOTICED the problem first and the oldest ist 6 month old (directly after the last fresh install of 8.1). No, I really consider if I NEED a CD READER ...

Comment: @igrimpe Did you try Nero BurnRights?  Also, what happens when you run diskmgmt.msc - does it recognize a DVD in the drive at all, and does it provide any info about the DVD?